# Unable to run my Flutter app with Firebase and having an error

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

**The error is following:**

../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_platform_interface-4.5.0/lib/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart(199,7): error GE33FC089: 'flutthrow' isn't a type. [C:\Users\Muhammad Umar\Documents\flutter_projects\android_ios\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]

**and Here is my main.dart file, can anyone tell me what's wrong here?**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _fbApp = Firebase.initializeApp();

  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: FutureBuilder(
          future: _fbApp,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('Something went wrong');
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return const MyHomePage(title: 'My Amazing Counter App!');
            }
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```